# Unable to import AWS SDK boto3 in Python 3.6.5

Tags: python, boto3

I'm trying to use boto3 within a pipenv with Python 3.6.5.
So I installed it with

```
pipenv install boto3
```

So for testing purposes I'm using a single Flask app, and add at the beginning of the file:

```
import boto3
```

However without even running the program, PyLint warns me that `E0401:Unable to import 'boto3'`, and the auto-completion only proposes `botocore`.
If I try to run the flask app or to deploy it to Lambda (cause it's the purpose of this app), I get an error 500.

However, the strange is that if I use the REPL within the pipenv and in the same directory and type

```
>> import boto3
```

Well it's successful, and I can use all the other commands of boto3. So in my opinion it is installed but for I reason I can't think of, my Python file can't load it.

I heard of file naming conflicts, but honestly I doubt that this is the reason since even if I rename the file and the Flask app with a weird name it still can't load.

Any thoughts about it? Thanks a lot